# Python: "infile" for loop won't run second time

Tags: python

I have two for loops that read from a file. They are both exactly the same, except for the `if` statement inside of them.

```
infile = open("australianFatalities.csv", "r")
for line in infile:
    words = line.split(",") 
    crash_id = words[0]
    crash_state = words[1]
    if crash_state == "NSW":
        print(crash_id)

for line in infile:
    words = line.split(",") 
    crash_id = words[0]
    crash_state = words[1]
    if crash_state == "NSW":
        print(crash_state)
```

The problem is that the first loop runs, but the second one does not. I know this because the `crash_id` will be printed, but `crash_state` will not. If I switch the `crash_id` and `crash_state` around, the state will print but the ID does not.
This code has been isolated from my main project, however displays the same issue.

Why would the loop not run the second time? Does it have something to do with reading off a file?

I'm new to Python, so the answer needs to be kept somewhat basic.

Comment: The first `for line in infile:` runs until there is nothing more to read, and, well, then there is nothing more to read. You can reset the file pointer with the function `infile.seek`.

Comment: By the time the second loop starts there aren't any lines left to read from the file, you have already read everything.

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks. It's been a while since I have worked with files, so I forgot that it won't automatically reset its position whenever you, for example, run the loop again.

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over a file object in python, the current position gets changed after each iteration.

Therefore, when you try to *loop* over the file object again, the cursor is at the end of file.

You can work around this by either opening the file again, or better: by invoking `fd.seek(0)` before the second loop.